# how to remove characters from beginning and end of a column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in sql which shows result like this
"T/PROD/Logs/somename.log"
what I want to do is only extract "somename" part from that string.
what I tried is

```
SUBSTR(A.SESSION_LOG_FILE, 41, LENGTH(A.SESSION_LOG_FILE) - 4)
```

but only removes the character from the beginning of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using such an approach, you'd select substring that begins after the last slash `/` characters and ends before the next non-word (in this case, a dot `.` character):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'T/PROD/Logs/somename.log' from dual)
  3  select
  4    regexp_substr(substr(col, instr(col, '/', -1) + 1), '\w+') result
  5  from test
  6  /

RESULT
--------
somename

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want between the last slash and the period, then one method is `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace('T/PROD/Logs/somename.log', '.*/([^/.]*).log$', '\1')
```

Comment: Thank you ,this works but could you tell me is it possible to replace the first element with the name of the column? because I want to do it for all the records on that column

Answer (score 0):

In Tsql, if "T/PROD/Logs/" never changes, I  would try to do this:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING('T/PROD/Logs/somename.log', 13, LEN('T/PROD/Logs/somename.log'))),5,LEN('T/PROD/Logs/somename.log')))
```